# neo4j: find similar users based on questionnaire alike answers

Tags: neo4j

I try to find similar users based on there answers in a questionnaire. The questionnaire contains questions like "job" -> answer "gardener" ->  importance "3". The special thing is that there is an field " importance " , so it is possible that users all answer gardener but with different importance values.

At the end I tried to find the users that are most similar to each other.

Thanks